# problem in spline with barriers in ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, editing, interpolation, 3d-analyst

I am trying to use the script tool "Spline with Barriers" from arcgis 9.3 3D Analyst toolboxes. I am not getting expected output. The output is just only one value over the surface. We are using ArcGIS 9.3 in XP Remote Desktop and it is a German Version of Windows, so the system represents the decimal place as a comma. Is it possible to edit this tool to store the field values as 3.40 instead of 3,30?

Comment: Are you sure this tool is a script tool? If I remember correct, this is a core ArcToolbox tool which is not exposed as a Python file. You cannot edit core GP tool. You should build either a model or a Python script that will pre-process input data to work with comma and points correctly. Playing with the OS Language and Region settings is another option.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on a script tool in ArcToolbox and select "Edit", it should bring up the Python script in IDLE.

That being said, I don't know if that will be able to fix how the decimal point is represented within the ArcMap table (I've never worked much with localization). [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530430/how-do-i-change-my-float-into-a-two-decimal-number-with-a-comma-as-a-decimal-poi) might get you further in the right direction.

Comment: I have got my solution and I am glad i did not Need to edit the script tool. This Problem has two solution: 1) When setting the cellsize use comma instead of 2.3 or 02) from control pannel Change the language of Computer to English(USA) ----Thanks for your cooperation